# decrypt random error with Laravel's built-in encryption facilities

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-encryption

I send invitation by mail to users with a encrypted email to know which user respond to invitation. Something like:

> Hello, click on this link to start learning: https://example.org/start-learning?e=fwTreaN0WybffXdDfZZUNYB3FTFfZObCb7QFF5C4AFJvTjXabIPtRfcoXLkFYMUvD4FIZsmrDdEFN2OPKcTrAOSQLZfuKdfwcic1WtBxWSXWR1GEJD6we213A3BEPBpca0BxaaQ4GGMPFeRyXp6fPrG9WnTgWogwXUcnVtdwSEEdNHGuZsClTxR2AtD2JZN8VAEsRQKpFFShEDR2SET4KxGhLGM3M0FdDelrJtO8KXS2YRaddH==

The encrypted email is the long string above. I encode mail like this in a `Mailable` class:

```
$url = 'https://example.org/start-learning?e=' . encrypt($this->to[0]['address']);
```

Then this `$url` is added in a mail template like this:

```
<a href="{{$url}}>click me<a>
```

Then, when user clicks the link, it routes to a controller and the controller decrypts the payload:

```
decrypt($request->input('e'));
```

Then, it works for about 99% of people clicking link. But for about one percent, it does not work, I have an error decrypting. And I don't know why. This is the same Laravel application which encrypts and decrypts. **Is there an reason for such a weird behavior?**

*Side note: I know decrypt always work and has not a random behavior (BTW I tested it on 10000 entries, it's OK). There must be something else with the mail process I don't understand.*

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to send the user a message id, and just retrieve that from the server when they request it, rather than encrypting your message to them and having them retrieve it through a get request?

Comment: This application send thousands mails and I don't want to store information before users accept to use the application. So it creates the participation only if users clicked the link and does some things.

Comment: have tried to use urlencode() and urldecode()?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `urlencode()` when creating link so instead of:

```
$url = 'https://example.org/start-learning?e=' . encrypt($this->to[0]['address']);
```

you should use:

```
$url = 'https://example.org/start-learning?e=' . urlencode(encrypt($this->to[0]['address']));
```

to make sure it will be valid.

Comment: Ok thanks. Even if I have a route like: "https://example.org/start-learning/abcdefg"? Anyway, I'm not sure the problem is here because I have got the full not working payload in my logs and it does not seem to have been altered by the http transport.

Comment: It depends how you create this route. If you create it manually you should probably still urlencode it, if you are using route or url helper you should look at code but probably Laravel does it under the hood.